# Gson @SerializedName for JSON enum value - can't display string value

Tags: java, json, enums

In the JSON web service call response, I need to display string value of enum.

Here is the xsd:

```
<xs:simpleType name="TokenTypeEnumType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="USERNAME" />
        <xs:enumeration value="JWT" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Here is the POJO object:

```
@XmlType(name = "TokenTypeEnumType")
@XmlEnum
public enum TokenTypeEnumType {

    USERNAME,
    @SerializedName("jwt")
    JWT;

    public String value() {
        return name();
    }

    public static TokenTypeEnumType fromValue(String v) {
        return valueOf(v);
    }
}
```

However, the response is still in ENUM instead of string value:

```
sxmTokenType: "JWT"
```

I'm looking for:

```
sxmTokenType: "jwt"
```

The lib gson-2.2.4.jar is on JBoss modules.

Thank you for your help!